# Error while attempting Android Studio Windows 11

Tags: android, windows, installation, sdk, adb

I am trying to install Android Studioon my Windows 11 laptop and I get the following error;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFTtu.png)

I did a quick search on the site and didn't see any results matching on the first few pages so I am posting a new question. Has anyone else experienced this and is there a fix for it?

Thanks, Ray.

Comment: Check your ENV variables, in detail `%TMP%` and `%TEMP%` if they point to an existing directory. Usually they should point to the Temp directory in your profile (local appdata).

Comment: Thanks for the response Robert. Are you referring to those locations on my laptop? I assume so because I don't think they are anything that would be on the site settings but i just want to be sure as i have not experienced such an error before and I've been downloading and installing applications on my computers for a good number of years. Anyway, I'll look into it and thanks again.